# On back press of fragment prevent to call onViewCreated of previous fragment using navigation graph

Tags: android, xml, android-fragments, navigation

I am using jetpack navigation to navigate between fragments.

I have two fragment **UserListFragment** and **ProfileFragment**. 
On `onViewCreated` method of UserListFragment called API of server and click of any item user will redirect to profileFragment.

If user **press back from ProfileFragment, then it should come to userListFragment which is working.** But `onViewCreated` method calls again so API is calling again to take data from a server. I don't want to call `onViewCreate` of first fragment. I want same behaviour as fragmentManager.add() not fragmentManager.replace().

Here is the code which I have written for navigating:

```
<fragment
    android:id="@+id/navigationUserListFragment"
    android:name="packageName.dashboard.UserListFragment"
    android:label="fragment_userlist"
    tools:layout="@layout/fragment_user_list">

   <action
        android:id="@+id/actionToProfile"
        app:destination="@id/navigationProfile"
        app:launchSingleTop="true"
        app:popUpTo="@id/navigationUserListFragment" />
</fragment>


<fragment
    android:id="@+id/navigationProfile"
    android:name="package.dashboard.ProfileFragment"
    android:label="profile_fragment"
    tools:layout="@layout/fragment_profile" />
```

So my question is to **how can I prevent to call `onViewCreated` when user presses back of the second Fragment.**

**Thanks in advance**

Answer (score 2):

OnViewCreated method will call whenever you come again to UserListFragment from ProfileFragment because whenever you are going to open new profile fragment then previous fragment's view will be destroyed.

For your task, I think you should use LiveData mechanism or manage your List data condition based if it has value then API should not call. Yes If there are any changes from profile screen then Interface through communicate.

Comment: I am looking for properties of navigation graph. yes, we can manage it using List data on a conditional basis but if it's properties of navigation then it will be better...